# Which circuit is more Stable?

Tags: microcontroller, transistors, relay, opto-isolator

[image]

The circuits in the picture are basically opto-couplers connected to a relay circuit. The input pin of the opto coupler is connected to a MCU and the output of the opto coupler is connected to the relay. Initially I was using circuit 1 but then I modified it to circuit 2 since it uses less components. Both the circuits are working perfectly. My question is that is circuit 2 more prone to spikes and could the MCU get damaged or short due to any abnormality in circuit 2. I am using the circuit for long term continuous use. Which circuit, out of circuit 1 and circuit 2 is more reliable for long term continuous use?

**IMPORTANT VALUES/LINKS**

**R5** = 330 Ohm

**JD-VCC** = 12V

**R6** = 10K

**U3** = 4N35SM Opto coupler(AVAGO)

http://www.comkey.in/sites/default/files/attachments/4N35-560E.pdf

**Q3** = BC847 (NXP)

Comment: Component values? Part numbers? Voltage? Without these things we cannot tell which circuit would be more reliable.

Comment: R5 = 330 Ohm
JD-VCC = 12V

R6 = 10K

U3 = 4N35SM Opto coupler(AVAGO)

http://www.comkey.in/sites/default/files/attachments/4N35-560E.pdf

Q3 = BC847 (NXP)

Comment: What are the relay specifications (esp. operate and release currents, coil resistance)?

Comment: Coil resistance = 400 Ohmn

Comment: Max current = 16 Amps

Comment: In circuit 2, can your optocoupler supply enough current to pull the relay?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The optocoupler isolates the two sides of the circuit from each other, so the MCU is protected from whatever happens with the relay.

The two circuits differ only in the extra transistor (Q3).
Such a transistor is used when you want to use a small curent to switch a larger current; this is necessary if the optocoupler cannot pass a current that is large enough for the relay.

The 4N35 has a CTR of at least 100 %, so the LED current must be as high as the current you want to allow through pins 3/4.
Furthermore, the LED current must be smaller than 60 mA, so the 4N35's collector current must not be larger than about 50 mA. (It should be noted that the LED wears out faster with higher currents.)

If your relay allows being switched with less than 50 mA (with 12V/400Ω = 30 mA, this is the case), and if the MCU is able to drive the LED with that current (which is unlikely), you can use the second circuit. Otherwise, you have to use the transistor to amplify the current.

Comment: good answer, but with a relay coil current of 30mA and a CTR of 100% the MCU has to drive the opto-coupler  with 30mA, which is beyond most MCU's. This makes Circuit 1 the best design.

Comment: Pardon me but what is CTR?

Comment: Also I am using JD-VCC as an external power supply to drive the relays. I am using the MCU anly to turn on the opto-coupler. Now according to you which circuit is better?

Comment: @RishiSharma [What is “Saturated CTR” of an optocoupler?](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/60443/29811) We don't know VCC_C or your MCU?

Comment: VCC of MCU is 3.3V